# react-router-dom conditional/protected Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I'm fairly new to React development. As first project, I want to create a Website with integrated CMS-y features for a social club. I am using *React*, *react-router-dom (v4)* and *firebase*. I had to set up protected routes, and at the moment my Routes look as follows:

```
<Switch>
      //other Routes with the same structure
      <Route path="/events" component={Events} />
      <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />  
      //other Routes with the same structure

      //Users have to be logged in from here on
      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/messages" component={Messages} />
      //other PrivateRoutes with the same structure

      <Route component={Home} />
      </Switch>
```

*PrivateRoute* is recommended by the *react-browser-dom-team* and looks as follows:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
<Route {...rest} render={props => (
 localStorage.loggedIn==="true" ? (
  <Component {...props}/>
) : (
  <Redirect to={{
    pathname: '/login',
    state: { from: props.location }
  }}/>
)
)}/>
)
```

My problem with it is that I have to save a *loggedIn*-flag in localStorage for the (separate) *PrivateRoute* to be able to check against it. I would like to use props (passed down to Main.js from App.js, where my firebaseOnAuthStateChange sits).

I then came up with simply writing protected Routes as:

```
<Route path="/dashboard" component={this.props.logged ? Dashboard : Login} />
```

This way, there's no redirect to the *Login* component when accessing */dashboard*, but it shows up until the user logs in and is then shown the desired Component.

**Now my question**: I did quite some research on the web, and only found the "PrivateRoute"-solution... Is something wrong with my approach? And what's the standpoint on localStorage?